Question on determining $f(1-i)$ for an holomorphic function $f:\mathbb{C} \mapsto \mathbb{C}$

Consider holomorphic $f:\mathbb{C} \mapsto \mathbb{C}$ with $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and that $f(1+i)=-1-i$.

And I'm interested in the possibility of finding $f(1-i)$ or knowing if there are no sufficient details. From the first condition, I have that $v(\mathbb{R},0) \equiv 0$ (and that $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} (x,0)=0$); furthermore, I know that $v(1,1)=-1$ and I thought of two examples of $v(x,y)$:
\begin{align*}
&v(x,y)=-y^3;\ v(1,-1)=1 \\[5pt]
&\overline{v}(x,y)=y(y-2); \overline{v}(1,-1)=-3 \neq1
\end{align*}
What leads to that conclusion that the conditions above are not restricitive enough. Is this conclusion right?

What's $v$? How does it relate to $f$?

$v=Im(f)$; the imaginary part of $f$

That information should be edited into the body of the question, not hidden down here in the comments

It's a simple exercise that if $f$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}$ then the function $g:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ given by $g(z)=\overline{f(\overline{z})}$ is holomorphic as well. Note that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$:
$g(x)=\overline{f(\overline{x})}=\overline{f(x)}=f(x)$
From the identity theorem it follows that $f=g$ as functions. In particular, for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ we have $f(\overline{z})=g(\overline{z})=\overline{f(z)}$, which means $f$ preserves conjugation. Well, $1-i$ is the conjugate of $1+i$.
